# How can I publish my Sharepoint Wiki so that users without a Microsoft account can access it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, public-website

In Confluence you can set an anonymous sharing of certain parts of the page. This allows users to access certain areas without having to log in. I'd like to do the same with SharePoint - is that even possible? I know that I can share something with individual users, but I have to add them all individually, etc.

What I want is that I just take the link of my Sharepoint Wiki and give it to the customers - otherwise I would have to invite each employee individually. What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Set the permissions of the wiki to "Anyone". Instructions are here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-files-outside-your-organization-with-anyone-links-53e91027-fb8e-4a6e-a3e4-5df4be32e38a

Answer (score 0):

Please do as following:

1. Navigate to your SharePoint Wiki page and click PAGE > Page Permissions.
   [image]
2. Click "Stop Inheriting Permissions" and then click "Grant Permissions".
3. Under "Get a link", select the link type with "no sign-in required" and then click Copy. 
   [image]

A guest link will be created and be valid before expiration date. It allows external users to have access to the page without signing in.

Comment: I would like to authorize an entire document library or website library, that external user can access the library with an normal link.

Comment: @SvenRösser I'm afraid that's currently not possible since external users are prevented from the Online environment by default. A guest link is required if you want to share with external users.